# React spring swipeable example without hook

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

Hello I'm trying to rewrite the swipeable cards example without hook (using render props), however I stuck in how to communicate Gesture with Spring. appreciate any help.

This is the official example with Hooks: https://codesandbox.io/embed/j0y0vpz59

This is my code trying to replicate the example with render props https://codesandbox.io/s/4j45p88qkw

what I'm unclear is the `bind` function, once I computed the new `x` `rot` `scale`, how to I pass it to the card?

Answer (score 2):

This example came from this discussion: https://spectrum.chat/react-spring/general/how-to-flick-something-off-the-screen-using-react-spring~37848d54-55ba-4a74-9a98-9aa42041177d Someone converted the hooks example, here's the thing running in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jnoqzplmj9

I would recommend hooks, though. There is nothing like it, renderprops start to have severe limits since they're mantling the view, while hooks are basically utility functions that bear no relation to any view, which makes it easier to combine them with things like gestures and so on.

Comment: I tried hard to recreate it, but there's still a lot of thing I don't understand quite well, for example the reset animation when all the card a swiped, new code https://codesandbox.io/s/82r0xlxzpl